# D3: Messed up coordinates with Cartogram.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, topojson, cartogram

Following the tutorial of Jeff Fletcher (http://www.limn.co.za/2013/10/making-a-cartogram/) I've been trying to build a Cartogram.js map of Europe.

I'm able to render the initial map, but when I do the transitions the coordinates get messed up.

The problem resembles this question: [using cartogram.js for visualizing information in a global map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707178/using-cartogram-js-for-visualizing-information-in-a-global-map)

Here is the code: https://github.com/jensfinnas/cartogram
Here is the live version: http://jensfinnas.github.io/cartogram/

Comment: Is it just the transition that causes the problem or are the second set of coordinates messed up on their own as well?

Comment: It is the second set of coordinates (the calculated once) that are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've flipped your lat / lon coordinates!

You've either passed them to a function somewhere that expects lon / lat and given it lat / lon, or the reverse, or the output from a function is doing the same,

I may get a chance to look at the code this week and update this answer with the exact place that's gone wrong.
[image]